# Find the second space and copy remaining text using MID and SEARCH in Excel

Tags: excel, substring

If I have a persons names as such

```
Sarah Jane Jones
Bob Jane Smithfield
```

How do I identify the second space and copy their last name into the next cell; B1 & B2 ?
From this reference [Excel Mid and Search Functions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SEARCH-SEARCHB-functions-9ab04538-0e55-4719-a72e-b6f54513b495?ui=en-US&rs=en-AU&ad=AU)

This example finds the first occurrence of a space and copies the subsequent characters in this case 4

```
=MID(A3,SEARCH(" ",A3)+1,4)
```

Following similarly

```
=MID(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1)+1,8)
```

returns
    Jane Jon
 and changing +2 only chops the "J" off.

Comment: I sugest something like `=MID(A1,FIND(" ",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","",1))+2,LEN(A1))` to be independant. just change the `1))+2` to `2))+3` to go for the text after the third space (or even higher for later parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula

```
=MID(A1,SEARCH(" ", A1, SEARCH(" ", A1) + 1), LEN(A1))
```

should work for you

Answer (score 0):

If search from last is available use that. I think it is there.

```
MID("Sarah Jane Jones", InStrRev("Sarah Jane Jones", " ") + 1)
```

I assume the name is in first, middle, last or first, last format.

Answer (score 0):

for first name-:

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(H2,FIND(" ",H2)),"")
```

for mid name-:

```
=IFERROR(MID(H2,FIND(" ",H2),FIND(" ",H2,FIND(" ",H2)+1)-FIND(" ",H2)),"")
```

for last name-:

```
=IFERROR(MID(H2,FIND(" ",H2,FIND(" ",H2)+1),10000),"")
```